# toUTF8String and local reference

Tags: c++, icu

http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#a05777d826515a20a0b2bb8f4108f9348

StringClass & toUTF8String (StringClass &result) const

Convert the UnicodeString to UTF-8 and append the result to a standard string.

Parameters: result
A standard string (or a compatible object)
to which the UTF-8 version of the string is appended.

Returns:
The string object.

```
// My own function.
string toStdString(const UnicodeString& a_str)
{
    string str;
    a_str.toUTF8String(str);
    return (str);
}
int main (void)
{
    string a = toStdString("a");
    string b = toStdString("b");

    cout << "a:" << a << endl; // a
    cout << "b:" << b << endl; // b

    const char* a1 = toStdString("a").c_str();
    const char* b1 = toStdString("b").c_str();

    cout << "a1:" << a1 << endl; // b !!! Problem: Why not "a"?
    cout << "b1:" << b1 << endl; // b

    const char* a2 = a.c_str();
    const char* b2 = b.c_str();

    cout << "a2:" << a2 << endl; // a
    cout << "b2:" << b2 << endl; // b

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `toStdString` returns a temporary, which goes away if you don't store it somewhere.

In this statement

```
const char* a1 = toStdString("a").c_str();
```

you store a pointer into this temporary object. At the end of the statement, this temporary string is destroyed again and the pointer points nowhere.

Trying to use the pointer later results in undefined behaviour and anything could happen, including displaying some other string.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with ICU, but rather that you are storing a pointer to a temporary object. When you call

```
const char* a1 = toStdString("a").c_str();
```

The `toStdString` returns a `string` object, then you call `c_str` on int, which returns a *temporary* pointer to its contents. After the `string` object is destroyed, the pointer is invalid and should not be used. In your case, the next call to `c_str` probably returned the exact same pointer to a temporary object, overwriting the previous one.